# Can I read the same file in two different methods within the same class?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm very new to coding. I'm learning java in a class from no experience at all.
I am using a text file with words on a new line for input.
The class I am creating has an object that uses string from the given file, Words, and a method with type String, getWord, which is supposed to output a random word from the given file. Here is an unfinished example of the code.

```
public class Words {

    public Words(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
       File inFile = new File(filename);
       Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);
    }

    public String getWord(Random rand){

    } 
}
```

When I try to do something within getWord, like in.hasNextLine, I receive a message that "in cannot be resolved". Am I able to use that same scanner from Words in getWord? I tried making a new File object in getWords but I am unable to input the variable filename.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: `in` is a **local** variable of your constructor and is not available outside of it.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make it available outside of the constructor?

Comment: Yes,  make it a  class variable.

Comment: Got it figured out. I ended up just writing all of my code in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should change your program like this.

```
public class Words {
Scanner in;
public Words(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File inFile = new File(filename);
    in = new Scanner(inFile);
}
............
}
```